# Clojure (or any functional language): is there a functional way of building flat lists by a recursive function?

Tags: list, recursion, clojure, flatten

I've got a recursive function building a list:

```
(defn- traverse-dir
  "Traverses the (source) directory, preorder"
  [src-dir dst-root dst-step ffc!]
  (let [{:keys [options]} *parsed-args*
        uname (:unified-name options)
        [dirs files] (list-dir-groomed (fs/list-dir src-dir))
```

... recursive call of **traverse-dir** is the last expression of **dir-handler**

```
  (doall (concat (map-indexed (dir-handler) dirs) (map-indexed (file-handler) files))))) ;; traverse-dir
```

The list, built by **traverse-dir**, is recursive, while I want a flat one:

```
flat-list (->> (flatten recursive-list) (partition 2) (map vec))
```

Is there a way of building the flat list in the first place? Short of using mutable lists, that is.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking.  `traverse-dir` doesn't build anything ... it returns `nil` because there's nothing in the `let` body.  You don't give us any idea what `listdir-groomed`, `dir-handler`, or `file-handler` are.  If you just want to flatten a list (as the title seems to imply), try searching stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your context with a `dir-handler` that is called with nothing and returns a function which expects indices and directories, `list-dir-groomed` and all of that, but I'd recommend a look at `tree-seq`:

```
(defn tree-seq
  "Returns a lazy sequence of the nodes in a tree, via a depth-first walk.
   branch? must be a fn of one arg that returns true if passed a node
   that can have children (but may not).  children must be a fn of one
   arg that returns a sequence of the children. Will only be called on
   nodes for which branch? returns true. Root is the root node of the
  tree."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
   [branch? children root]
   (let [walk (fn walk [node]
                (lazy-seq
                 (cons node
                  (when (branch? node)
                    (mapcat walk (children node))))))]
     (walk root)))
```

My go-to use here is

```
(tree-seq #(.isDirectory %) #(.listFiles %) (clojure.java.io/as-file file-name))
```

but your context might mean that doesn't work. You can change to different functions for getting child files if you need to sanitize those, or you can just use `filter` on the output. If that's no good, the same pattern of a local fn from nodes into pre-walks that handles children by recursively mapcatting itself over them seems pretty applicable.